# How to get all messages defined for a built-in symbol?

Tags: message-coding

AFAICT, when given a built-in symbol as argument, `Messages` returns an empty list, at least initially.

For example:

```
Quit (* reset *)
```

```
Messages[ListPlot]
```

> `{}`

After running `??ListPlot`, however, I get

```
Messages[ListPlot]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[ListPlot::usage] :> ListPlot[{y1, y2, …}] plots points {1, y1}, 
> {2, y2}, …. 
> ListPlot[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, …}] plots a list of points with specified x and y
> coordinates. 
> ListPlot[{data1, data2, …}] plots data from all the datai.
> ListPlot[{… , w[datai, …], …}] plots datai with features defined by the
> symbolic wrapper w.}
> ```

If I then elicit some error message, e.g. by running `ListPlot[{1, 2, 3}, PlotRange -> InvalidPlotRangeSetting]`, I get

```
Messages[ListPlot]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[ListPlot::prng] :> Value of option PlotRange -> `1` is not All,
> Full, Automatic, a positive machine number, or an appropriate list of range
> specifications.,
> HoldPattern[ListPlot::usage] :> ListPlot[{y1, y2, …}] plots points {1, y1}, 
> {2, y2}, …. 
> ListPlot[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, …}] plots a list of points with specified x and y
> coordinates. 
> ListPlot[{data1, data2, …}] plots data from all the datai.
> ListPlot[{… , w[datai, …], …}] plots datai with features defined by the
> symbolic wrapper w.}
> ```

IOW, it's like pulling teeth...  Totally impractical.

Is there a *practical* way to *really* get all the messages associated with a built-in symbol?

Comment: Note that some messages actually belong to `General`, e.g. `General::prng`.

Answer (score 4):

You can read them directly from the `Messages.m` file.

```
path = FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Kernel",
    "TextResources", "English", "Messages.m"}];

allMessages = Import[path, "HeldExpressions"];

symbolToLookup = ListPlot;

Select[allMessages, MemberQ[#, symbolToLookup, Infinity, Heads -> True] &]
```

To get usage messages load `"Usage.m"` instead of `"Messages.m"`.